# Generic Static Class as Service Locator

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, static, monogame

I am applying the Service Locator pattern as [described in Game Programming](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/service-locator.html) Patterns, and am wondering about a possible generic implementation. The following code *does* work, but I am confused about using a class that is both generic and static.

The idea of the following C# code is to provide a "global" service to other parts of the application, exposing only an interface rather than the full implementation. Each service registered using this method will only have one instance in the application, but I want to be able to easily swap in/out different implementations of the provided interfaces.

My question is: when I use the following class to provide different services throughout my application, how does C# know that I am referring to different services of different types? Intuitively, I would almost think that the static variable, `_service`, would be overridden with each new service.

```
public static class ServiceLocator<T>
{
    static T _service;

    public static T GetService()
    {
        return _service;
    }

    public static void Provide(T service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
}
```

Here's some usage:

```
// Elsewhere, providing:
_camera = new Camera(GraphicsDevice.Viewport);
ServiceLocator<ICamera>.Provide(_camera);

// Elsewhere, usage:
ICamera camera = ServiceLocator<ICamera>.GetService();

// Elsewhere, providing a different service:
CurrentMap = Map.Create(strategy);
ServiceLocator<IMap>.Provide(CurrentMap);

// Elsewhere, using this different service:
IMap map = ServiceLocator<IMap>.GetService();
```

Comment: `public static class ServiceLocator<T>` it means that you wii have many closed types of `ServiceLocator'1`. So if you use `ServiceLocator<ICamera>` and `ServiceLocator<IMap>` you will have two `static T _service;` objects. You are right, when you use `ServiceLocator<T>.Provide` it will rewrite a value of ` _service;` but it will rewrite value only for closed type `ServiceLocator'1`. It means that `ServiceLocator<IMap>.Provide(CurrentMap)` will rewrite the `static IMap _service;` but will not rewrite the `static ICamera _service;` in case above

Comment: I have a generic service locator I use for cases when dependency injection is unavailable. I'll post it tomorrow when I have my work computer.

Comment: @ScottHannen Thanks, that'd be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# creates a separate closed type for every combination of generic parameters for open type.
Since every combination of generic parameters creates a separate class, calling a static constructor and creating own members for each of them. 
You can think of them like of different classes.

```
public static class GenericCounter<T>
{
    public static int Count { get; set; } = 0;
}

GenericCounter<int>.Count++;
GenericCounter<int>.Count++;
GenericCounter<string>.Count++;
Console.WriteLine(GenericCounter<double>.Count); // 0
Console.WriteLine(GenericCounter<int>.Count); // 2
Console.WriteLine(GenericCounter<string>.Count); // 1
```

This code outputs:

```
0
2
1
```

For example, in your case, behavior will be *the same* as if you created two separate classes:

```
public static class ServiceLocatorOfIMap
{
    static IMap _service;

    public static IMap GetService()
    {
        return _service;
    }

    public static void Provide(IMap service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
}

public static class ServiceLocatorOfICamera 
{
    static ICamera _service;

    public static ICamera GetService()
    {
        return _service;
    }

    public static void Provide(ICamera service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
}
```

and used it like this:

```
// Elsewhere, providing:
_camera = new Camera(GraphicsDevice.Viewport);
ServiceLocatorForICamera.Provide(_camera);

// Elsewhere, usage:
ICamera camera = ServiceLocatorForICamera.GetService();

// Elsewhere, providing a different service:
CurrentMap = Map.Create(strategy);
ServiceLocatorForIMap.Provide(CurrentMap);

// Elsewhere, using this different service:
IMap map = ServiceLocatorForIMap.GetService();
```

In general, it is similar to what C# does when it meets static generic classes.

Comment: That's great! Thanks for the explanation. I figured it worked along these lines, but wanted to make sure I wasn't starting to dig myself in a hole by misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

I use this for cases where I can't use dependency injection all the way down (like WebForms) but I want to write testable classes that are resolved by a DI container.

The usage looks like

```
using(var resolved = new ResolvedService<ISomeService>())
{
    resolved.Service.DoSomething();
}
```

The good:

- You can use a DI container to resolve and release resources
- It's disposable, and disposing causes the container to release the resources
- It keeps the container and service registrations out of sight

The bad:

- It requires a static class, but that's also in the composition root so it's not too bad.
- As written it depends directly on Windsor. It's easy to replace that with any other container. Maybe one day I'll break this apart so that `ServiceLocator` isn't coupled to any particular container. But for now it's trivial to change that.

Using this means that while the larger component (like an .aspx page) isn't testable, what I inject into it is testable. It just gave me a crazy thought - I could write orchestrators for WebForms pages so that they're mostly testable. But hopefully I'll never need to do that.

```
internal class ServiceLocator
{
    private static IWindsorContainer _container;

    internal static void Initialize(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }
    internal static TService Resolve<TService>(string key = null)
    {
        if (_container == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "ServiceLocator must be initialized with a container by calling Initialize(container).");
        }
        try
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)
                ? _container.Resolve<TService>()
                : _container.Resolve<TService>(key);
        }
        catch (ComponentNotFoundException ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("No component for {0} has been registered.", typeof(TService).FullName), ex);
        }
    }

    internal static void Release(object resolved)
    {
        _container.Release(resolved);
    }
}

public class ResolvedService<TService> : IDisposable
{
    private bool _disposed;

    private readonly TService _resolvedInstance;

    public TService Service
    {
        get { return _resolvedInstance; }
    }

    public ResolvedService(string key = null)
    {
        _resolvedInstance = ServiceLocator.Resolve<TService>(key);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~ResolvedService()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed) return;
        ServiceLocator.Release(_resolvedInstance);
        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't have been more wrong about replacing one container with another being "trivial." The challenge is in how they release resources. It's doable, but now the challenges of writing DI-agnostic code mixed with service location are ugly and call for some compromise. There are still cases when it's worth it. So I'm calling it "Desperation."